# Rational approximation for irrational number

Tags: irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

Sometimes I go into some subject in the class (high school level) and I have to explain to my students how approximate an irrational number by a sequence of rationals. The problem is that I should explain that in a high school level. What I usually do is take $\pi$ as a example and take the sequence:
\begin{align}
& 3,1=31/10\\
& 3,14=314/100 \\
& 3,141=3141/1000 \\
& 3,1415=31415/10000\\
&\vdots
\end{align}
I think that approach is intuitive and the students feel satisfacted with that. I was trying to figure out another way to explain the rational approximation but I coudn't find any. My questions is, does anyone know another way to explain that approximation in a high school level?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is also continued fractions, which will give you fractions that are not necessarily decimal fractions.

Comment: You could see: http://www.ams.org/samplings/feature-column/fcarc-irrational2

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.  Any decimal can be approximated by it's truncation...if you cut it at the $n^{th}$ place (after the decimal) the error is no greater than $10^{-n}$.  There are better approximations, of course.$\pi\sim \frac {22}7$, famously, or $\frac {333}{106},\frac {355}{113}$ and so on...but these are harder to generate.

Comment: @Ihf: How to do that in a high school level?

Comment: @lulu: truncation is what I usually do. I was wondering if could be another approach in a high school level.

Comment: Well, continued fractions are elementary in the sense that the manipulations are not difficult.  Still, they are fairly abstract and building up the apparatus takes more time than you are likely to want to spend.  Personally, I'd go with interesting examples instead.  Talk about [tempering](http://oeis.org/DUNNE/TEMPERAMENT.HTML) on a keyboard, say.  How useful it is that $\left( \frac 32 \right)^{12}$ is very close to  $2^7$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Newton's method for square roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method#Square_root_of_a_number) can be a good candidate due to its simplicity.

For example for approximating $\sqrt2$ in few iterations. You can ask your students where do they think $\sqrt2$ is located. Between $1.41$ and $1.42$, then you can start with $x_0=1.41$

$g(x) = x - \frac{(x^2 - 2)}{2x}$

$g(1.41) = 1.41 - \frac{(1.41^2 - 2)}{2\cdot1.41} = 1.4142198581...$

$g(1.4142198581) = 1.4142135623 \approx \sqrt2$

Answer (score 0):

I think high schoolers can understand Farey sequences.  The $n$th Farey sequence is all the fractions between $0$ and $1$, inclusive, with denominators less than or equal to $n$.  $F_5 = \{0,1/5,1/4,1/3,2/5,1/2,3/5,2/3,3/4,4/5,1\}.$  If your irrational number is between $0$ and $1$, then it lies between two of those fractions.  By increasing $n$, there are more and more fractions and some of them get closer to your number.  Wiki has a page:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence

I don't think this is more intuitive, but it has the advantage of leading to a number of elementary exercises.